# SQL Server 2012: An older Index that used to help a SP overnight

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, index, optimization

Hopefully this isn't a repeat question. I haven't had much luck finding an existing answer.

I have an index on a somewhat large table (About 60 million rows, 25gbs with indexes) that has been in existence, unchanged for about 2-3 years and a stored procedure that is also untouched for about 2-3 years that relies on this index. The SQL server that both reside on has its statistics updated at 5AM each morning. This server is a subscriber to another DB that also has the same SP, table, and index. The table is replicated to the server in question.

Literally overnight this stored procedure went from running for under a second to running up to 45 minutes causing CPU to spike to 100%. On the publisher server, this same stored procedure uses the identical table + index still under a second when executed.

While I can't get an actual execution plan, I can see the estimated and the index seek estimated a CPU cost of like 200,000 instead of the usual 7-9.

I tried updating statistics on the table (despite the morning job) with fullscan. I've tried dropping and recreating the index.

Ultimately, dropping this index caused the stored procedure to use a new plan which is much faster (done in seconds), but the actual execution plan of course is asking for the index that I dropped.

Any ideas, in general, what would make a plan and/or index spike CPU like this so suddenly?

Thanks

EDIT:

[Link to High CPU Plan](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9vej6i1ja9v18tu/High_CPU.sqlplan?dl=0)

[Link to Low CPU Plan](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1rrhl2j9ibij3qy/Low_CPU_From_Publisher.sqlplan?dl=0)

```
ALTER Procedure Schema1.Object1

@ID char(3) = ?
```

AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
        DECLARE Variable1 integer

SELECT Variable1 = Column1 FROM Object2 WHERE Column2 = Variable2

IF Variable1 IS NOT NULL AND Variable1 > ?
  BEGIN

```
SELECT DISTINCT Object3.Column3 AS Column4
```

, Object3.Column5
   , Object3.Column6
   ,(Object3.Column5 + ? + Object3.Column6) AS Column7
   FROM Object4
   JOIN Object3 ON Object3.Column3 = Object4.Column3
   WHERE Object4.Column1 = Variable1
        AND Object4.Column8 = ?

UNION SELECT 
   DISTINCT Object3.Column3 AS Column4
   , Object3.Column5
   , Object3.Column6
   ,(Object3.Column5 + ? + Object3.Column6) AS Column7
   FROM Object5 Object6
   INNER JOIN Object7 Object8 ON Object8.Column9 = Object6.Column9
   INNER JOIN Object3 ON Object3.Column3 = Object6.Column10
   WHERE Object6.Column11 = ? 
   AND Object6.Column8 = ? AND Object8.Column8 = ?
   AND Object8.Column1 = Variable1

UNION select ?, ?, ?, ?
  ORDER BY Object3.Column5, Object3.Column6

```
END
```

Comment: Can you post the SP and the (estimated or actual) execution plan?

Comment: Usually it's parameter sniffing, but it's sort of hard to tell exactly without being able to see more. You should search around for those terms to see if the symptoms match your situation, assuming you can't provide more info.

Comment: Have you tried comparing the plan on the publisher with the plan on the subscriber.  It would be easier to troubleshoot when u see the difference.

Comment: [Maybe worth a read...](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-the-runaway-query/)

Comment: Before I do anything, like stats update, re-index, I would suggest you do a sp_recompile '<your SP in question>'. This will force the SP to do an recompilation. From your description, it is surely an Execution Plan (EP) sub-optimized, it can be parameter sniffing or just a bad EP reuse. Recompiling SP will most likely (60% chance IMHO) fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, All. I've edited the OP and added some links to the two different SQL plans. One from the publisher that has no trouble with the SP and one that has high CPU use.

Definitely think this could be an issue with parameter sniffing.

@jyao I did try recompiling a few times during the issue, but SQL Server seemed determine to reuse the same plan until I completely removed the index.

Comment: Also added the stored procedure.